# this.variable = NaN inside jquery's click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<div id="mydiv">lol</div>
```

javascript:

```
var oWM = new WM();
oWM.Add("mydiv");
oWM.Initialize();

function WM() {
    this.ZIndex = 1000;
    this.Windows = [];
    this.Add = function(id) {
        this.Windows.push(id);
    }
    this.Initialize = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.Windows.length; i++) {
            $("#" + this.Windows[i]).click(function () {
                alert("#"+this.id + ":" + this.ZIndex++);
                $("#" + this.id).css("z-index", this.ZIndex++);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

when the user clicks on the div i get a "Nan" for **this.ZIndex**, so my change-zindex-on-click function doesn't work. Why doesn't it get recognized and how can i make it work?

I think it has something to do with jquery's $() function because **this.Windows[i]** is also undefined inside that block.

http://jsfiddle.net/79sM8/

click on the "lol" div and see what happens

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because inside of your click event, `this` is the element you clicked on, not the WM object.

The simplest fix would be to `bind` the click function's `this` value ahead of time:

```
$("#" + this.Windows[i]).click(function () {
    alert("#"+this.id + ":" + this.ZIndex++);
    $("#" + this.id).css("z-index", this.ZIndex++);
}.bind(this);
```

---

**EDIT** - turns out you want to read the `id` property off of the element that was clicked, so the above probably won't work in this case since you still need `this.id` to refer to the dom element's id.

Definitely learn how to use function.bind, but for this problem, the solution below is what you want

---

Of course this won't work in IE8 (without a shim) so if that's a problem, you can just save the `this` value of your WM object ahead of time and use *that* in the click handler:

```
this.Initialize = function() {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Windows.length; i++) {
        $("#" + this.Windows[i]).click(function () {
            alert("#"+ this.id + ":" + self.ZIndex++);
            $("#" + this.id).css("z-index", self.ZIndex++);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: self.id will error out, as it doesn't point to the element. His original this.id will work, as it's the DOM element's id he's accessing.

Comment: You also don't need to re-query using `$("#" + this.id)`, just `$(this)` will do.

Answer (score 3):

The variable 'this' inside your click handler is scoped to the element clicked, rather than the WM object. you should cache the WM object outside the click handler. That way you can use it from within the click handler's scope.

```
var oWM = new WM();
oWM.Add("mydiv");
oWM.Initialize();

function WM() {
    this.ZIndex = 1000;
    this.Windows = [];
    this.Add = function(id) {
        this.Windows.push(id);
    }
    this.Initialize = function() {
        var that = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.Windows.length; i++) {
            $("#" + this.Windows[i]).click(function () {
                alert("#"+this.id + ":" + that.ZIndex++);
                $("#" + this.id).css("z-index", that.ZIndex++);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context within a jQuery event handler is set to the DOM element triggering the event. Thus, `this` inside your click handler will refer to one of your `Window` elements.

To get around this, you should keep a local variable referring to the original `this` scope and use that inside the handler:

```
this.Initialize = function() {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Windows.length; i++) {
        $("#" + this.Windows[i]).click(function () {
            alert("#"+this.id + ":" + self.ZIndex++);
            $(this).css("z-index", self.ZIndex++);
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can forcefully set the correct `this` context on your event handler using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), although that method is new in ECMA-262 and not yet present in all browsers. The linked MDN page provides more details.

Comment: self.id will error out, as it doesn't point to the element. His original this.id will work, as it's the DOM element's id he's accessing.

Comment: @steve_c Good catch! I also noticed that there's no need to do another query for the DOM element using `"#" + this.id`, just `$(this)` suffices.